# Initialises list object in locals in middleware but its not working

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I am trying to an Initialises list object in locals in middleware to display locals in index view template but it's not working.

```
exports.initLocals = function (req, res, next) {

res.locals.navLinks = [
                { label: 'Home', key: 'home', href: '/' },
                { label: 'Contact', key: 'contact', href: '/contact' },
                { label: 'Products', key: 'products', href: '/products  ' },
];
res.locals.cart = keystone.session.cart;            
res.locals.user = req.user;

keystone.list('Category').model.find().sort('name').exec(function (err, results) {

    if (err || !results.length) {
        return next(err);
    }
    locals.data.categories = results;
});

next();
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. I had made two mistakes. First I called the `next()` method outside of the scope of the list query.

Secondly I was not referencing `locals.categories` correctly.

```
//get top three category
keystone.list('Category').model.find().sort('name').limit(3).exec(function (err, results) {
    if (err || !results.length) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
            res.locals.categories = results;
                next();
            }
});
```